# How to install different version of Redis in K8S using helm

Tags: redis, kubernetes-helm

I was looking into how to install a specific version of redis (not latest) in kubernetes using helm.

```
[root@GEN-FNZC0F3 redis]# helm install redis-v627 bitanmi/redis-cluster --version 7.6.4 --set usePassword=true --set cluster.nodes=6 --set persistence.storageClass=standard --set persistence.size=1G -n infra
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed to download "bitanmi/redis-cluster" at version "7.6.4"

[root@GEN-FNZC0F3 redis]# helm install redis-v627 bitanmi/redis-cluster --set=image.tag=6.2.7 --set usePassword=true --set cluster.nodes=6 --set persistence.storageClass=standard --set persistence.size=1G -n infra
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed to download "bitanmi/redis-cluster"
```

Please let me know if you have any any way to pass the chart or image version in the CLI.

Thanks

Comment: Did you misspell `bitnami`?

Comment: The [Bitnami Redis chart documentation](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis) does describe an `image.tag` Helm value, and the last command you show seems right to me (other than the spelling of the chart name).